# Can we search on Stack Overflow based on or condition over tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, search, tag-search

I can search through tags using [tag-name] and then add a search term that I want to search like. For multiple tags I can also search with [tag-name-1][tag-name-2][tag-name-3]. But it filters the questions by joining the tags using AND conditions. So if a question has all the tags then it will come in the result set, otherwise not.

However, I want to search the questions based on joining the tags by OR conditions. Like I want to filter the questions which either came in PHP or Java.

Is it possible to search like that on Stack Overflow...?

Comment: [Cross posted to Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297573).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes combine the tags with or,

[php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) in [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+javascript).